# Official way to download workshop items in SteamCMD

Tags: steam, steam-workshop, steamcmd

Is there any official way to download workshop items in SteamCMD running on an off-site server? Examples would be maps for CS:GO or Garry's Mod. It is possible to download the files from a third-party website with `wget` or upload them using FTP. But is there an official way to subscribe to them so that SteamCMD downloads them and manages the updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using [Steam's Workshop](http://steamcommunity.com/workshop/).

First of all, you need an [API Key](https://steamcommunity.com/login/home/?goto=%2Fdev%2Fapikey) that's going to be placed inside your server configuration script ([script for CSGO](https://gameservermanagers.com/lgsm/csgoserver/)). Then, it deppends on what kind of items you want to implement in your server but, for CSGO maps, you just need to add their *workshop id* to your `mapcycle.txt` (it also works for collections).

For different kind of items, I'd be different (*as you are obviously not going to add a AK47 Skin to your map rotation*) but the procedure would be very similar.

By adding content to your server this way, you ensure that it's going to be updated (make sure you find the right item and not *copy & pasta* ones)

Comment: Do you coincidentally know how it works for Garry's Mod maps?

Comment: Nope, sorry. Have only managed CSGO servers..

Answer (score 0):

About Garry's Mod

You can't download addons with SteamCMD but IIRC you can with srcds (Source Dedicated Server) downloadable via SteamCMD which I won't be covering, this is long enough as it is

This also covers regular addons

I have worked with workshop maps on dedicated servers if that is what yours wondering, I launch my server through a .bat file so everything is set up for a single file.

Firstly, Gmod doesn't use map cycles, its exists so that mountable games can't load their one mapcycle.txt and cause errors, but knowing the workshop theres probably an addon that can cycle maps or at the very least let you change it without needing to start a new server.

I have a link to some srcds info and a .bat template
[Right here](http://www.srcds.com/db/engine.php?subaction=showfull&id=1097362093)

To get addons in GMod servers you need to create a steam workshop collection with what you wish to have

then add -authkey followed by your API Key somewhere after /wait srcds.exe, you should have got one with CSGO from Alex

Finally add +host_workshop_collection followed by the ID of your collection, to see this either use your web browser or the steam client with URLs turned on and load your collection page, you are looking for the string at the end after ?id=

And then if you have an map addon simply replace it with whatever workshop map you want to start with

IIRC the server checks the addons for updates everything you launch the server and automatically downloads them for you

If all goes well the addons should download and the server should start, then you should be able to connect to it with your addons correctly downloaded, just make sure you have the same addons before trying to connect

Yeah, this was about as confusing my first time around getting addons to a dedicated server, I wish you luck

*If anyone beats me to this I will literally flip*